# request.get_json() works on localhost but not remote host

Tags: python, json, flask

This is probably the weirdest error I have ever run into and I have spend the past 48 hours trying to figure out a solution. Basically I have a Flask application that I have been developing for the past year and a half. Everything works, except for one of my final tasks. I am trying to integrate Elasticsearch with the application and so far everything has worked on my local machine (Mac OS X Catalina). However, when I put the same code on the server, (DigitalOcean CentOS 7), it fails.

Specifically I am trying to get json data and incorporate it in my search string which is passed to Elasticsearch. The relevant code is below:

from flask import request, g, Blueprint, json, Response, current_app, url_for

```
@search_api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required
def search():
    """
    Full text search against user and events models
    """
    req_data = request.get_json()
```

I have used very similar code in 60+ other API endpoints, and none are functioning incorrectly. The weirdest thing is it works on localhost. I have even done print statements and I can verify that `request.get_json()` is returning an empty dict. However, that is only on the remote box, not the local machine.

This is a bug that I cannot seem to fix, so hopefully someone might have seen this before and can point me in the right direction. Flask version is 1.0.2.

I am making the requests with Postman. I have tried cURL and that returns the same error as well.

EDIT: Forgot to add the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

That error is directly related to request.get_json() not getting any data. I print the contents of that dict is empty. So the issue is the json is not being passed to the function.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Jortega: I edited the question with the error.

Comment: It looks like `request` is `None`.  First you have to make `request`  equal to some response. Example: `request = reqs.get('http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/group_list')`

Comment: @Jortega I am trying not to hard code URL's in my reuqest string. This same format works for 60+ endpoints I have in this app. This is the only one that fails.

Comment: Add the line `print(request)` we need to know what `request` is.

Comment: I printed it and it is coming back as none. On my localhost, it is not empty. But on the server it is.

Comment: Please add the code section where `request` is defined. What you currently have posted is not where the issue is.